# How can I save an array to UserDefaults, and then retrieve that array and print

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code. It seems an error. Can anyone please help.

```
class PopUpVC: UIViewController {
  var myArray1 = ["1","2","3"]
  var myArray2 = [String]()
  UserDefaults.standard.set(myArray1, forKey: "array")

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myArray2 = (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "array") as? [String])!
    print(self.myArray)
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416414-stringarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PopUpVC: UIViewController {
  var myArray1 = ["1","2","3"]
  var myArray2 = [String]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      UserDefaults.standard.set(myArray1, forKey: "array")
      self.myArray2 = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array")!
      print(self.myArray2)
 }
```

Comment: That answer is just wrong. You don't retrieve an Array of Strings using `Userdefaults.string(forKey:)`, you do it using `array(forKey:)` or `object(forKey:)`, then cast it to `[String]`. Have you even tested that code? It wouldn't even compile, since you are trying to give a `[String]` default value to a `String?` variable.

Comment: i have used is not `String(forKey:)`  I used is `StringArray(forKey:)`

Comment: Yeah that's correct i was accepted your edit.