# swift: Add value from array

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save value in array and check if value in array exist.

I use this code:

to save value

```
var index = 0
var array = [Int]()

self.array.append(self.index)
```

But how I can check if value in array exist and show numbers values in array in console?

example:

check value

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if "values for array exist" {

    //show text for all row numbers in the array 
    }

}
```

save value in array

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    index = indexPath.row
    self.array.append(self.index.row) //save row number

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value in array = true" and "show next code"?

Comment: Who upvoted this ... question??

Comment: @Sweeper I want to add value in array. Check value in array exist. And if value in array exist I should show : `// my next code` .

Comment: what do you mean by "code"?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed any code, for example show numbers values in array in console

Comment: Your explanation is still hard to understand. Showing an example input and an expected result would explain what you really want to do better. Please add an example (or some examples) into your question.

Comment: your index is of type int and you are trying to append it to an string type array how does it possible, correct your question as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = 0
var array = [String]()

array.append("\(index)")
```

How to see all that is inside the array

```
array.forEach({print($0)})
```

you could also do:

```
for i in 0..<array.count{
    print(array[i])
}
```

to check if the array contains:

```
print(array.contains("5")) // false
print(array.contains("0")) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you want to find a value exist in array or not so:

Take an example:

```
let array = ["one","two","three","one"]
var newArray:Array<String> = []

for obj in array {
 if newArray.contains(obj) {
    print(newArray)
}else {
    newArray.append(obj)
}
}
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Update question

Comment: @user use the contain method for check if value exist

Answer (score 0):

Just change your cellForRowAt tableview delegate method as below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

if array.contains(indexPath.row) {

       print("Rows in arrays are \(array)")
  }

}
```

Comment: It is works. But can I save value in array with User.defaults? I need to show text in cells after back in previous controller and return in this controller. And if I back in previous controller my array is empty. I use the navigation bar to move between my TableViewControllers. Or there are better way to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957220/how-can-i-save-an-array-to-userdefaults-and-then-retrieve-that-array-and-print/45957586#45957586

Answer (score 0):

The **Swift way** is pretty easy, using [index(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index) you can validate your value and if it exist, meaning, index(where:) returned the index you need, remove it.

Code snip:

```
if let index = array.index(where: { $0 === 1 }) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: @user, Code snip is exactly what you need, as you wrote *if "value for array exist" * - This is what the first code snip does.

Comment: In array I save numbers of row. In `cellForRowAt` I should show text for numbers of rows in array.

Comment: So your problem with the code snip is the type ? - updated answer